# Is there a unnecessary part in this definition of "not connected set" in complex plane?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

In the book "Introduction to complex analysis" - Junjiro Noguchi, there is a definitoin of *not connected set* in complex plane as follows

[image]

Here, $A$ is a subset of complex plane. I think the part $\cap A$ in $U_1\cap U_2\cap A=\emptyset$ is not necessary. Am I wrong?

Comment: It is necessary, otherwise you could choose any open $U$ that intersects $A$ and let $U_1=U_2 = U$. Basically all non empty sets $A$ would be not connected.

Comment: @copper.hat But then you would not have $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$.

Comment: My mistake, I missed the $\cap A$ part of your question.

Comment: There may be a topology where $A$ is disconnected but there are no disjoint $U_1,U_2$ in the topology separating $A$. That is, they separate $A$ in the subset topology but not in the ambient topology.

Comment: Might be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1879490/27978

Comment: In particular, metric spaces have this property, so the $\cap A$ can be dropped in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is made so that it works in a general topology setting: $A$ in the subspace topology is a disconnected space. In a metric (or more generally a herditarily normal) space we get an equivalent definition if you omit the $\cap A$ in the final clause, see [this question and its answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1879490/4280), but also note that it is easier to show disconnectedness using the stated definition, as we only have to ensure that $U_1$ and $U_2$ do not intersect in $A$, instead of at all. So I'd stick to this definition anyway, especially because it's also valid in any topological space you will encounter later.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just illustrating a point that is too long for a comment.

Let $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $\tau=\{ \emptyset, \{a\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, X \}$ and let $A= \{b,c\}$.

With the definition above, $\{a,b\}$ and $\{a,c\}$ separate $A$.

If you omit the $\cap A$, then $A$ is non not connected.

Comment: I wonder if there's an example in $\mathbb C$ with the usual topology (the OP's setting). In $\mathbb R$, I think the $\cap A$ can be removed without consequence: just pick a point $x$ such that $A$ contains points to the left and right of $x$ but excludes $x$ itself. Then take $U_1 = (-\infty, x)$ and $U_2 = (x, \infty)$. But there's a lot more wiggle room in two dimensions.